# How to join 4 tables in mysql PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 4 tables as below:

*1) **courses***

```
   | ID - > Primary Key | Name
   -------------------------------
   | 1                  | Course 1
   | 2                  | Course 2
   | 3                  | Course 3
```

*2) **countries***

```
   | IDPrimary Key | Name
   -------------------------------
   | 1                  | Country 1
   | 2                  | Country 2
   | 3                  | Course 3
```

*3) **universities***

```
   | ID - > Primary Key | Name           | country_id
   ---------------------------------------------------
   | 1                  | University 1   | 1
   | 2                  | University 2   | 1
   | 3                  | University 3   | 3
```

*4) **university_courses***

```
   | ID - > Primary Key | university_id  | course_id
   ----------------------------------------------
   | 1                  | 1              | 2
   | 2                  | 3              | 2
   | 3                  | 3              | 3
```

Now, I need to create one **REST API** in ***core PHP*** for android app in that I will get two parameters ***`country_id`*** and ***`course_id`***. Both will contain multiple values like ***`country_id = "3,4,5"`*** and ***`course_id = "1,6,8"`***.

I have to response all the ***related universities*** according to the ***country*** and ***course***.

I have tried below query but i am not getting desired output so please help me if anyone have idea for my problem.

```
SELECT * 
FROM universities 
    LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.id = universities.country_id 
    LEFT JOIN university_courses ON universiity_courses.university_id = universities.id 
    LEFT JOIN courses ON courses.id = university_courses.course_id 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(universities.country_id, ?) 
AND FIND_IN_SET(university_courses.course_id, ?)
```

If `course_id = 1,2` and `country_id = 2,3`, my desired output should be:

```
| university_id |
| 3             |
```

Comment: You want to use the IN() operator

Comment: Any way we can use, but need proper output.

Comment: You are using LEFT JOIN which is wrong you need to use a INNER JOIN to get the related relations. Also you JOiN to much tables then you could. You only have to need to JOIN between university_courses and the universities to get the required results

Comment: Okay, now above issue is partially solved.

Comment: But now i m getting same university twice, if `course_id=2,3`. So in short `Group by` is not working.

Comment: I do not see Group by in the Question

Comment: This is query with group by:
`SELECT cd_universities., university_courses., COUNT(*) FROM cd_universities LEFT OUTER JOIN university_courses ON university_courses.university_id = cd_universities.university_id LEFT OUTER JOIN cd_courses ON cd_courses.course_id = university_courses.course_id LEFT OUTER JOIN cd_countries ON cd_countries.country_id = cd_universities.country_id WHERE FIND_IN_SET(university_courses.course_id, ?) AND FIND_IN_SET(cd_universities.country_id, ?) GROUP BY university_courses.university_id;`